# start service under logged on user account by changing token

Tags: delphi

I have a desktop application that installs and starts a service. I know a process can get the explorer.exe token and launch another process with that token so as the second process will run us the logged on useraccount.

My question is this: can I start my service by this explorer.exe token too? Is there an example in Delphi?

thx for your time

Comment: Maybe you could tell us what your intentions are so we can give you a better answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you cannot use such a trick to launch a service in a specific user account.  The service's configuration in the SCM specifies the user account that the service uses when started.  You can use `ChangeServiceConfig()` to change that account, but be careful because it is a global setting, not a per-start setting.